# Not able to select the checkbox of a html row

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

**MY CODE:**

```
package com.drishti.automate.testing;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class DeleteUserFromAdmin {

    WebDriver driver;

    public DeleteUserFromAdmin(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void testDeleteUserFromAdmin() {

        WebElement searchUser = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".searchBoxRowStyle.searchBoxStyle.row"));

        WebElement enterUserNameInSearchField = searchUser.findElement(By.tagName("input"));

        enterUserNameInSearchField.sendKeys("testautomationuser");

        enterUserNameInSearchField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));

        List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        for (int z = 0; z < allRows.size(); z++) {

        }

    }

}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<tbody>
    <thead class="tableFloatingHeader" style="visibility: visible; display: none;">
        <tr>
            <th id="col0" class="selection">
                <input value="on" id="gwt-uid-466" tabindex="0" type="checkbox">
                <label for="gwt-uid-466"></label>
                <div style="height: 100%; display: flex;"></div>
            </th>
            <th id="col1" class="sortable">
                <div style="height: 100%; display: flex;">
                    <i style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" class="tiny material-icons"></i>
                    <span class="table-header">User ID</span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th id="col2" class="sortable">
                <div style="height: 100%; display: flex;">
                    <i style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" class="tiny material-icons"></i>
                    <span class="table-header">User Name</span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th id="col3" class="sortable">
                <div style="height: 100%; display: flex;">
                    <i style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" class="tiny material-icons"></i>
                    <span class="table-header">User Role</span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th id="col4">
                <div style="height: 100%; display: flex;">
                    <i style="cursor: pointer; float: left;" class="tiny material-icons"></i>
                    <span class="table-header">Actions</span>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr style="height: 10px; max-height: 10px; min-height: 10px;" class="data-row">
        <td id="col0" class="tableCheckBoxStyle">
            <input value="on" id="gwt-uid-467" tabindex="0" class="filled-in" type="checkbox">
            <label for="gwt-uid-467"></label>
        </td>
        <td id="col1" data-title="User ID">
            <div class="cell">testautomationuser</div>
        </td>
        <td id="col2" data-title="User Name">
            <div class="cell">testautomationuser</div>
        </td>
        <td id="col3" data-title="User Role">
            <div class="cell">Administrator</div>
        </td>
        <td id="col4" data-title="Actions">
            <div class="widget-cell">
                <a style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <span>Edit</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image: Scenario]

Comment: show us your html *source* (I don't know what that "HTML CODE" is).  Also your 'z' loop has no content and does nothing, huh?

Comment: For 'z' loop--  I do not how to proceed? Sorry, I am a beginner.

HTML:

Comment: <tbody><tr class="data-row" style="height: 10px; max-height: 10px; min-height: 10px;"><td id="col0" class="tableCheckBoxStyle"><input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-401" tabindex="0" class="filled-in"><label for="gwt-uid-401"></label></td><td id="col1" data-title="User ID"><div class="cell">testautomationuser</div></td><td id="col2" data-title="User Name"><div class="cell">testautomationuser</div></td><td id="col3" data-title="User Role">

Comment: <div class="cell">Administrator</div></td><td id="col4" data-title="Actions"><div class="widget-cell"><a style="cursor: pointer;"><span>Edit</span></a></div></td></tr></tbody>

Comment: What is the error you're facing. Secondly your table has `display` set to `none`. Thirdly, I don't see that you're clicking on any checkbox in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you take all rows of the table (**including header row**). According to your html-code **there should be a check-box in the header row, however I cannot see one on the screenshot you provided**.

[image]

The issue you have might be connected by the fact the top **check-box is hidden by applied styles**.

So when you are doing

```
for (int z = 0; z < allRows.size(); z++) {

}
```

you loop through the rows starting from very first one (header row). You can work around your issue by changing `int z = 0;` to `int z = 1;` if you are sure that your table will always have header row. So eventually your loop will look like this:

```
for (int z = 1; z < allRows.size(); z++) {
  WebElement rowInput = allRows.get(z).findElement(By.tagName("input"));
  // work here with input of a particular row
}
```